# NullPointerException in my program

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am trying to get the following program to run. However, a `NullPointerException` is showing up. I have debug my code every step of the way thus far. It seems that the null pointer exception comes about after I implement the `numA.add()` in main.

Main.java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[]args){

        NumberSystem numA = new NumberSystem(new Number(20),new Number(10));
        numA.add();
        System.out.println(numA.getResult().toString());
    }
}
```

NumberSystem.java

```
public class NumberSystem {

    private Number n1,n2,result;

    public NumberSystem(){
        n1 = new Number(0);
        n2 = new Number(0);
        result = new Number(0);
    }

    public NumberSystem(Number n1,Number n2){       
        n1 = new Number();
        n2 = new Number();
        result = new Number(0);
    }   

    public NumberSystem(NumberSystem n){
        n1 = new Number(n.n1);
        n2 = new Number(n.n2);
        result = new Number(n.result);
    }

    public Number getN1(){
        return n1 = new Number(n1.getNum());
    }

    public Number getN2(){
        return n2 = new Number(n2.getNum());
    }

    public Number getResult(){
        return result = new Number(result.getNum());
    }

    public void setN1(int n1Value){
        if (n1Value != 0) n1 = new Number(n1Value);
    }

    public void setN2(int n2Value){
        if (n2Value != 0) n2 = new Number(n2Value);
    }

    public void add(){
        result = new Number(n1.getNum() + n2.getNum());
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "" + n1.getNum();
    }

}
```

Number.java

```
public class Number {

    private int num;

    public Number() {num = 0;}
    public Number(int numValue){
        if (numValue != 0) num = numValue;
    }

    public Number(Number anotherNum){
        num = anotherNum.getNum();
    }

    public int getNum(){
        return num;
    }

    public void setNum(int numValue){
        if (numValue != 0) num = numValue;
    }   

    public String toString(){
        return new String("" + num);
    }

}
```

Comment: You must tell us which line throws the NPE.

Comment: It's a custom class, the source of which he has posted.

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign values to the class member variables in your constructor of `NumberSystem`. Currently you are only assigning these values to the local values with the same names which are passed in.

```
public NumberSystem(Number n1,Number n2){       
    n1 = new Number();  // Number assigned to local variable n1
    n2 = new Number();  // ditto for n2
    ...
```

This then causes an `NPE` then you attempt to assign the result on this line:

```
result = new Number(n1.getNum() + n2.getNum());
```

Instead you could use:

```
this.n1 = new Number();
this.n2 = new Number();
```

or use the values passed in(!?):

```
this.n1 = n1;
this.n2 = n2;
```